# A CommThemeLayoutPage flexi-page installed from a managed package appears to be neither editable or updatable

Tags: community, tooling-api, community-builder, flexipages, custom-theme-layout

We have a Community (AKA Digital Experience) packaged including LWCs and many flexi-pages (of type `CommAppPage`) that leverage a couple of theme flexipages (of type `CommThemeLayoutPage`).

I can find no way - via the "Builder" - to edit these themes once the package is installed. And an upgrade of the package does not update the themes either.

See the lock next to TEMPLATE HEADER and lack of editing widgets in this Builder screen shot:

[image]

In other areas the platform takes one approach or the other: make the component locally editable but don't overwrite those changes during a package upgrade or no local editing but a package upgrade installs the latest. Here it is neither, apparently leaving the first template you installed as the locked version for eternity.

I can think of 2 solutions:

- Perhaps there is a Tooling API that can be used to do the editing and it is that the "Builder" is just missing the functionality to do that. So I would need to write some Tooling API logic.
- Perhaps the editing capability is in the "Builder" and I just can't find it; great if someone can point the way there.

If you have experienced this problem please comment or answer here.

**PS** Some more Googling reveals [Is the Template Header region customizable in a Community?](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000316222&language=en_US&mode=1&type=1). But pretty unclear what "Template Header Top" is.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what appears to happen. Based on a couple of hours of work so certainly not definitive.

When a new "Digital Experience" is created starting from a template (that includes the theme layout), a copy of the template is created. That works fine for the parts that the page builder makes editable. But the template header is not editable, though the template footer is. (These templates were created a year ago: this problem might relate to the starting point or have been introduced sometime since.)

If the managed package is upgraded with a new theme layout, I haven't found a way to get that change incorporated into existing "Digital Experiences". It is possible to use the Tooling API to change the theme layout `FlexiPage`, but it appears that a clone is created per "Digital Experience" and AFAIK there is no API to change that clone (as well as no UI in the page builder.)

However, new "Digital Experiences" created after the upgrade do incorporate the latest theme layout.

So my conclusions are:

- Be cautious about putting components in the theme layout header or footer, testing early to make sure that they are editable in existing "Digital Experiences" (as for me they were not in the header).
- If they are not editable, perhaps plan to not use the header and footer and instead put components into regions that are editable e.g. individual page headers and footer.
- I've resorted to using a single LWC header component and footer component so should change to operational "Digital Experiences" be needed there is at least a way to make change through the contents of those LWCs.

Would be very happy to hear that I've misinterpreted what is going on and that there is a simple way to solve the problem.